# Removing <img > when a4j:commandbutton pressed not working

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have two a4j:outputPanels, one that should not be displayed if the the `imageSet` boolean on the backing bean returns false.

The other outputPanel has an `a4j:commandButton` and the action calls `removeImage` which sets imageSet = false. However, when it reRenders `image` the image is still displayed. Is it possible storing the image in the cache and still displaying it?

The image is still located where the `src` is pointing, I just do not want it displayed when this button is pressed. Any ideas?

```
       <a4j:outputPanel id ="image"
                             rendered="#{userInfo.imageSet}">
                    <img id="signatureImage"
                         src="/document/signature?imageId=#{userInfo.imageId}"
                         alt="No Image"/>
                    <br/>
        </a4j:outputPanel>

        <a4j:outputPanel id="Display">                                          

            <a4j:commandButton id="removeButton"
                           action="#{userInfo.removeImage}"
                           immediate ="true"
                           value="Remove Uploaded Signature"
                           disabled="#{!userInfo.stampSet}"
                           rendered="#{userInfo.editMode}"
                           onclick="this.disabled=true"
                           ajaxSingle="true"
                           styleClass="delete-button"
                           reRender="image">
            </a4j:commandButton>

            [Other things here, not relevant] 

        </a4j:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Based on code it should work as you expected. There are not visible problems. I only can suggest replace img with `h:graphicImage`, which is native JSF and has `rendered` attribute (use this attribute and after re-rendering panel it take an action).

Comment: @VasilLukach unfortunately that didn't work. I'll keep looking to see if something else is stopping it from re-rendering properly and update if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Placing it all in a panelGroup works. not rendering the outputPanel would make there be no img tag to update/remove from the screen, leaving the image on there.

```
<a4j:outputPanel id ="image">
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{userInfo.stampSet}}">
       <img id="signatureImage"
            src="/document/signature?signatureId=#{userInfo.userStampId}"
            alt="No Image"/>
        <br/>
  </h:panelGroup>
 </a4j:outputPanel>
```